# Google SMTP issue in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail, laravel-8

It has now been one week and I have tried multiple solutions to make Google smtp work with laravel.

My problem: my laravel mailer with Google smtp works on my local environment, but not online.

My `.env`:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myadressmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypasswordappgoogle
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myadressemail
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I tried a lot of tutorials, but nothing works.
Does anyone have any ideas?

<------------------- problem solved ------------------->

I finally managed to get the google smtp to work, the problem was with my server firewall (OVH).

Comment: Many shared hosting providers (like GoDaddy) block outbound SMTP because spam. Check that you can actually connect to that server/port from your hosting environment.

Comment: My server is located at OVH and it works normally. I have a firewall and an authentication system, I tell myself that maybe that's it ..

Comment: Let me rephrase. Log in to a shell on your server. From there, use telnet to verify that you can connect to port 465 on smtp.googlemail.com. Also check your application's error logs -- what error is the Laravel mailer reporting?

Answer (score -1):

Just use below credentials in .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YourGmailHere
MAIL_PASSWORD=YourPasswordHere
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@exapmle.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Then run the following command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: This does not work I have already tested, I have an authentication system on my site the time to put it online for security I tell myself that maybe that's what is blocking?